# SQL Parse soap xml and show as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, soap

I am trying to return the ErrorReason from the below soap xml response. However it keeps returning empty. I am not sure how to handle the namespace.

I expect to return "*The specified envelope has duplicate recipients.*"

```
declare @xml xml =
(
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b0c43031-35b9-40a1-a217-36491cfdd07c</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:4871a441-ea1e-4f9b-953b-d3f426674597</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-c41a3e0c-317d-46e2-b203-6a0a43450313">
        <wsu:Created>2017-08-31T18:11:00Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-08-31T18:16:00Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>The specified envelope has duplicate recipients. </faultstring>
      <faultactor>https://www.test.asmx</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">140</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">The specified envelope has duplicate recipients.</ErrorReason>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
)



select  x.value('ErrorReason[1]','VARCHAR(max)') from @xml.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/detail') as X(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

you want the below query

```
select @xml.query('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:Fault/*:detail/*:ErrorReason/text()')
```